# Write messages with ordering_key to Google PubSub using Apache Beam and Python

Tags: python-3.x, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

I am trying to write Google PubSub message with ordering_key to a topic using Apache Beam (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher). Although Google Pubsub with ordering_key is a beta feature, I am able to publish messages using a normal PubSub client library. I would expect to be able to do it in Apache Beam as well. However, it does not seem to be anything available for Python Apache Beam library.
I have been trying to override beam.io.WriteToPubSub (by changing _to_proto_str) to write a protobuf message with ordering_key  (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1#google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage). In the end the message will be like this

```
  "data": string,
  "attributes": {
    string: string,
    ...
  },
  "messageId": string,
  "publishTime": string,
  "ordering_key": string
}
```

```
sdks.python.apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubMessage._to_proto_str
  def _to_proto_str(self):
    msg = pubsub.types.pubsub_pb2.PubsubMessage()
    msg.data = self.data
    for key, value in iteritems(self.attributes):
      msg.attributes[key] = value
    msg.ordering_key = self.ordering_key
    return msg.SerializeToString()
```

However, the ordering_key seems to be disappear when I look at the end message which end up in my topic. In the worst case, I guess I could use PubSub client to publish the messages as well.
But, it would be better if someone could point me to the right direction for the kind of change. I know contributor in apache Beam project must have done something similar because they have included a feature to change attributes on PubSub messages awhile ago.

Updated : Apache Beam 2.24.0 depend on an old version of PubSub Client library. I think because they want to keep support for Python 2 a bit longer. But, everything may come to the end around 7 Oct (at least for Google, they stop support Python 2 for Dataflow after that date). Everyone else may need to wait for any version after 2.24.0.

For a workaround, I have successfully installed the newest PubSub client library on the top of Apache Beam 2.24.0. And create new custom PubSub IO as DoFn (you just need to override setup method and create Publisher Client in there). I am able to publish messages with ordering key now. But, I am not sure whether anything broker because of my change or not, it is fine for demo purpose.

```
 def setup(self):
        publisher_options = pubsub_v1.types.PublisherOptions(
            enable_message_ordering=True
        )
        self.publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(
            publisher_options=publisher_options,
            batch_settings=pubsub_v1.types.BatchSettings()
        )
```

Comment: I recommend you to open an issue on the [Beam project](https://github.com/apache/beam)

Comment: Have open one just before see your comment https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-10958 . Not sure, I would set it as bug or improvement actually. Thank you for the suggestion anyway.